# Loading reference data tables using Flyway

Tags: flyway

Our application has a number of tables containing reference data.  We have been using the traditional Flyway approach of creating delta files for each change in data but with frequent changes its a bit hard to manage this way.  It would be easier to have a script with a truncate followed by inserts to reload the table from scratch and when data changes the developer would edit this file as needed.

Is there a clean way to accomplish this in Flyway without generating checksum errors?  Hopefully without creating a new version of the load script each time a change is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your reference data as a beforeMigrate [callback script](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks.html)?

"Using the default settings, Flyway looks in its default locations (/sql) for the Command-line tool) for SQL files like beforeMigrate.sql, beforeEachMigrate.sql, afterEachMigrate.sql"

Comment: That's getting closer to a solution.  The callback runs after every migrate unconditionally.  Ideally this script is executed only when its checksum changes.  Also would be good if the solution supported multiple script files - callbacks are limited to one script file.

Comment: Interesting checksum idea. I'm not sure it would work in all cases because there could be some valid use cases where it is used to set the target database or server configuration as changes may have happened outside of Flyway. I'd suggest you wrap your reference data INSERTs inside an IF statement if you don't want to rebuild the reference data each time. Would that work for you? What's your backend database?

Comment: Two target databases currently.  Developer testing uses H2 and formal DEV / UAT/ PROD uses Oracle 11g.  A runtime 'if' condition could be useful.  Would that rely on a capability of the underlying DB or does Flyway have some support there?